# Why is my program only taking one input before completing?

Tags: c

This program uses an array and three functions to read inputs, sum up the ones and tens place of inputted integers, and compute the average of input integers. Why can't I get more than one input that is a positive integer? The program runs after one input that is within the limits of integers that are valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_data(int Ar[]);
void comp_sums(int Ar[], int size); // prototypes
double comp_avg(int Ar[], int size);

int main()
{
    int Ar[100];
    int size;
    double avg;
    size = read_data(Ar);
    comp_sums(Ar, size);
    avg = comp_avg(Ar, size);
    printf("The average of the integers in the array: %lf\n", avg);
}

int read_data(int Ar[])  // reads inputted integers, stores in array
{
    int flag;
    char ch;
    int i,j, num;

    flag = 1;
    i = 0;
    while (flag == 1) {
        printf("Please enter an integer:\n");

        j = scanf("%d", &num);
        if (j != 1) {
            break;
        }

        if (num < 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (num >= 100) {
            flag = 0;
        } else {
            Ar[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
}


void comp_sums(int Ar[], int size)   /* computes sum of ones and tens place of the inputted integers into the array*/
{
    int i, j;
    int sum_ones, sum_tens;
    sum_ones = 0;
    sum_tens = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum_ones += Ar[i] % 10;
        j = Ar[i] / 10;
        sum_tens += j % 10;
    }
    printf("The sum of the ones is: %d\n", sum_ones);
    printf("The sum of the tens is: %d\n", sum_tens);
}

double comp_avg(int Ar[], int size) // computes average of integers
{
    int i, sum;
    double avg;
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += Ar[i];
    }
    avg = (double)size / sum;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code is not a luxury. It's a requirement, and specially when you want others to read it.

Comment: Format your code so it is sane and readable and you'll see `return i;` is inside your loop, and will unconditionally execute. Thus, one iteration, thus one input.

Comment: I did it for you, but just because I executed `astyle -A3 your-code.c` ...

Comment: `read_data` should take that length of the array as second argument and you should check the you don't access `Ar` out of bounds.

Comment: Also, `read_data()` currently does not return from all execution paths, so it's a potential for *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

When you take an array as an argument, you have to take the length as well,
because you have to check if you are reading/writing out of bounds. Forget for a
second that the return is at that incorrect position, the user **can** input more
values than the array can hold and you are doing nothing to prevent the buffer overflow.

So to fix your `read_data` function:

```
int read_data(int Ar[], size_t len)
{
    if(Ar == NULL || len == 0)
        return 0;

    int i = 0, j, num;

    // imortant to check the bounds
    while (i < len) {
        printf("Please enter an integer:\n");

        j = scanf("%d", &num);
        if (j != 1) {
            break;
        }

        if (num < 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (num >= 100) {
            break;
        } else {
            Ar[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

I removed the `flag` bit because if `num >=100`, you would be ending the loop
anyway, so it's much simpler to do a `break`. Also the intention is more clearer.

Now you can call it:

```
int main()
{
    int Ar[100];
    int size;
    double avg;
    size = read_data(Ar, sizeof Ar / sizeof *Ar);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what it's wrong with the answer? If there's something wrong, so give me the chance to fix it.

Comment: @4386427 thanks for you replay, I appreciate it. If it was a honest mistake thanks for telling me this and fixing it. I was a little mad about this, not because I was downvoted, but because I saw absolutely no reason for it. I don't mind being downvoted (and it has happened to me) when I haven't been careful and posted wrong code or when I posted nonsense, everybody do mistakes, but it makes me mad, when people (in general) downvote and go away. For me as person who writes a lot of answers, a downvotes tells me "you wrote non-sense" and I'd like to improve myself and learn from my mistakes...

Comment: ... but when no comment is left behind, then I cannot what I might have done wrong. So I don't mind that you've made an error and downvoted me by mistake, thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call `return` inside the `while`loop. So as soon as you get a valid number, you'll return from the function.

Move it outside the loop. Like:

```
while (flag == 1) {
    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");

    j = scanf("%d", &num);
    if (j != 1) {
        break;
    }

    if (num < 0) {
        continue;
    } else if (num >= 100) {
        flag = 0;
    } else {
        Ar[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
    // return i;  Incorrect
}
return i;  // Correct
```